# How to add a parameter in VMWare WorkStation

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I am trying to add the parameter `disk.EnableUUID=true`.
I am doing these steps that I found:

1. Click VM Options tab, and select Advanced.
2. Click Edit Configuration in Configuration Parameters.
3. Click Add parameter.
4. In the Key column, type disk.EnableUUID.
5. In the Value column, type TRUE.
6. Click OK and click Save.

I don't see the option to add a new parameter.
Is there another way to add parameters?
I use VMware Workstation 15 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the .vmx file for your VM, and add this line at the end of the file:

```
disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"
```

Save the file and boot the machine.